# Specify expiration for static resources in order to leverage browser caching

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, browser-cache

When I run the Google Chrome Page Speed on one of the web sites I created, I got the following warning for lots of static resources *(.js, .jpg, .png, .css files)*;

> The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime.
>   Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the
>   following resources:
>   http://www.example.net/Content/App_Icons/Exported/MC900304631.png
>   (expiration not specified)

My app is an asp.net and asp.net mvc hybrid app and running on windows server 2008 r2, IIS 7.5.

How can I enable that feature? Couple of moths ago, I heard something about ***eTag*** bhut don't if it has anything to do with that. could provide examples or good resources on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try this?
http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache

Comment: yeah, I did the same couple of days ago and it's totally for me now. It sends the response with all the stuff, ETag and etc. for browser caching. thanks though.